# Specifying image size in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

In doxygen documentation for `\image` [doxygen documentation for image](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage), it does not say anything about using percentage. However, the followings

```
\image html some.png width=50%
```

actually resizes the image to 50% of the page width.

In my case, I would like to resize images to 50% of their original sizes in stead of the page width. Is there a way to achive that?

**EDIT:**
I am using doxygen version 1.8.17, and my output format is HTML.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which output format are you talking about HTML, LaTeX, Rtf, ?

Comment: @albert I am using doxygen version of 1.8.17, and I am outputtting HTML. (Sorry for the late response, I was away for a few days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen is giving the width verbatim to the underlying renderer. In the HTML the image tag looks like to specify for the width, officially, only pixels so it is up to the browser what to do with it. I did some investigations and it looks like in the css there are some possibilities with `transform: scale(0.5,0.5);` or `transform: scaleX(0.5);`

This won't work with the `\image` command, but does work with the `<img>` doxygen HTML command, so you could use:

```
<img src="some.png" alt="" style="transform: scale(0.5,0.5);" />
```

Edit: Added a quote mark before `some.png`.

Comment: Thanks. This works.